# How can I copy specific values from one Excel worksheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to make a macro to copy some values to a new worksheet to assemble a database. I got a macro that takes the values in the yellow cell and one to unmerge. I needed to copy some specific values to the new table based on the initial text "PV", thus copying the entire cell.

It would have to copy the values from cell F19 and L19 to the end of the column, and then copy the values to another worksheet.

Cells to copy

[image]

new worksheet

[image]

but I can't think of a way to select the cells that have the description of "PV"

I already managed to use:

```
Sub SelectByColor()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim FoundRange As Range

Set rng = Range("E1:T19")

For Each cell In rng.Cells
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
Set FoundRange = cell
Else
Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, cell)
End If
End If
Next cell

If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then FoundRange.Select

End Sub
```

need to select specific text then copy.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Matching Rows

[image]

```
Sub CopyMatches()

    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "F19"
    Const SRC_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "F,L" ' or e.g. "A:C,F,J:M"
    
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    Const BEGINS_WITH_CRITERIA As String = "PV"
    Const RETRIEVE_UNIQUE_ONLY As Boolean = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim slrg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set slrg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim sData()
    
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = slrg.Value
    Else
        sData = slrg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, sStr As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sStr = CStr(sData(sr, 1))
        If InStr(1, sStr, BEGINS_WITH_CRITERIA, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            If RETRIEVE_UNIQUE_ONLY Then
                If Not sDict.Exists(sStr) Then
                    sDict(sStr) = sr
                End If
            Else
                sDict(sr) = sr
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If sDict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no matches
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = sDict.Count
    
    Dim sColumns() As String: sColumns = Split(SRC_COPY_COLUMNS, ",")
    Dim scUpper As Long: scUpper = UBound(sColumns)
    
    Dim sJag(): ReDim sJag(0 To scUpper)
    
    Dim srg As Range, sc As Long, dcCount As Long
    
    For sc = 0 To scUpper
        Set srg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(sColumns(sc))
        dcCount = dcCount + srg.Columns.Count
        If srCount * srg.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
        Else
            sData = srg.Value
        End If
        sJag(sc) = sData
    Next sc
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim sItem, dr As Long, dc As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each sItem In sDict.Items
        dr = dr + 1
        For sc = 0 To scUpper
            For c = 1 To UBound(sJag(sc), 2)
                dc = dc + 1
                dData(dr, dc) = sJag(sc)(sItem, c)
            Next c
        Next sc
        dc = 0
    Next sItem
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(dr, dcCount)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
    MsgBox "Matches copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

modify source sheet name accordingly and on which row in column F you want to start `For i = 2 To lastRow`

```
Sub CopyValues()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim planilha1Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long,rw as Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    rw = 1

    ' Set the source sheet and Planilha1 sheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    Set planilha1Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
    
    ' Find the last row in column F of the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column F starting from row 2
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Check if the cell value starts with "PV"
        If Left(sourceSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value, 2) = "PV" Then
            ' Copy the values from column F and L to Planilha1
            planilha1Sheet.Cells(rw, "A").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value
            planilha1Sheet.Cells(rw, "B").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, "L").Value
            rw = rw + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```